# Absolutely convergent vs conditionally convergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence

Why is the series $a_n={1\over2^n+n}$ convergent whereas the series $a_n={3^n+1\over4^n+5}$ is *absolutely* convergent? Since both use the comparison test to the geometric series, what makes one abs. convergent and the other not? I know a series converges absolutely if $|a_n|$ converges so why the difference?

Answer (score 0):

A series that is positive is absolutely convergent as soon as it is convergent. So both are absolutely convergent.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought..

Comment: (That's what I thought) vs (what makes one abs. convergent and the other not?)